# Why is this subclass' parent method call not polymorphic?

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism, d

I've been dabbling in Dlang recently as C++ just wasn't quite sitting right with me after having used Python for so long.  While dabbling, I came across what I thought would be a very simple exercise in polymorphism.  I suppose how you would expect something to work and what it actually does are two entirely different things for reasons an end user probably can't comprehend.  That being said, here is the source code of my "sandbox.D":

```
import std.stdio;

class Animal {
    string voice = "--silence--";
    void speak() {
        writeln(this.voice);
    }
}

class Dog : Animal {
    string voice = "Whoof!";
}

int main() {
    auto a = new Animal();
    auto d = new Dog();

    writeln(a.voice); // Prints "--silence--"
    writeln(d.voice); // Prints "Whoof!"

    a.speak(); // Prints "--silence--"
    d.speak(); // Prints "--silence--" NOT "Whoof!"

    return 0;
}
```

I guess my issue is why the "this" keyword just doesn't seem to be functioning how you would expect it to in the C++ successor language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods are polymorphic, variables aren't. So instead of making the voice a variable, you want to `override speak` in the child.

Also, the `auto` return type doesn't work with polymorphism, you need to actually specify the types. (The reason is that auto return makes a function template in the compiler, which in theory could have multiple overridable slots in the function table, so it just doesn't try to put it in.)

So try this out:

```
import std.stdio;

class Animal {
  void speak() { // changed to void instead of auto
    writeln("--silence--");
  }
}

class Dog : Animal {
  override void speak() { // the override tells it to override the base method
    writeln("woof");
  }
}

int main() {
    auto d = new Dog();
    d.speak();
    return 0;
}
```

If you have a lot of shared functionality and want to reuse one function with slight changes in child classes, you might make a method instead of a variable that just returns something.

Like `string voice() { return "woof"; }`, then it can be overridden in children.

Comment: Ah, I appreciate such a timely response!  I was debating whether to remove some of the "auto" keywords.  Ultimately, I tried it without auto and declaring the proper types but it didn't make a difference.  I guess that object oriented inheritance doesn't seem quite as useful as I had imagined :(

Comment: It is useful, just gotta remember that only methods are overridable, variables aren't. (I'm not sure if it is the same in Python, but it does generally work that way in a lot of OOP languages). Though, inheritance does have its limits; you can solve a lot of things with it, but it isn't always the best way.

Comment: It's plenty useful. You just have to understand how to use it, and you misunderstood how it worked. You just need to override the function instead of the member variable, and it works fine. The code length isn't even much different. And if you want to override a member variable instead, just wrap it in a function to return its value and use the function instead of using the variable directly. But I've never heard of a language that overloaded variables, and given how polymorphism works underneath the hood, it would pretty much mean wrapping them in functions underneath the hood anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use template this parameter:

```
import std.stdio;

class Animal {
    string voice;

    void speak(this C)() {
        writeln((cast(C)this).voice);
    }
}

class Dog : Animal {
    string voice = "Whoof!";
}

int main() {
    auto a = new Animal();
    auto d = new Dog();

    a.speak(); // Prints ""
    d.speak(); // Prints "Whoof!"

    return 0;
}
```

Or when you do not need to have voice as a member:

```
import std.stdio;

class Animal {
    static immutable voice = "";

    void speak(this C)() {
        writeln(C.voice);
    }
}

class Dog : Animal {
    static immutable voice = "Whoof!";
}

int main() {
    auto a = new Animal();
    auto d = new Dog();

    a.speak(); // Prints ""
    d.speak(); // Prints "Whoof!"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The brunt of my confusion was just with "this" not referring to the Dog's voice but instead the base Animal's voice.  I guess properties are not quite the same in Dlang as I thought they would be :)